# Symfony adding additional Route parameters

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am trying to add new parameters to the route.

Example Route: config/routes.yaml

```
admin_account_list:
    path:       /accounts
    controller: App\Admin\Controller\Account\AccountController::list
    methods: [GET, POST]
    newParam: // I want to add this
```

Is there a way to determine the class to be run whenever this route is used

Comment: What do you mean by _"the class to be run"_?

Comment: I need a method that I can enable when using this route.

Comment: That's the controller action - `AccountController::list`.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html I want to add the "IsGranted" property to the route. To prevent access to packages I have overwritten.

Comment: I can actually solve this problem using "access_control". But it would be simpler to add on the route.

Comment: You can use a kernel request listener to check for the existence of your parameter then call isGranted as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
admin_account_list:
path:       /accounts
controller: App\Admin\Controller\Account\AccountController::list
methods: [GET, POST]
defaults:
    page: 1
    title: "Hello world!"
```

try this it may help you